# Expected Value of difference of i.i.d rv's by integrating cdf

Tags: probability-theory

So the problem is:

Given two independent random variables, call them $X,Y$ with $F$ as a cumulative distribution function, we are ask to prove the following statement:

$E[|X-Y|] = 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(t)(1-F(t))dt $

My work:

Due to $X,Y$ being i.i.d, then $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(Y,X)$, so:

$P(X\leq Y) = \mu_{(X,Y)}(\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x \leq y \}) = \mu_{(Y,X)}(\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x \leq y \}) = P(Y\leq X) $.

Variable $Z=-Y$ is obviously independent of $X$, due to $Y$ being so ( function $f(s) = - s$ is borel)

We know that for $E[|S|] = \int_0^\infty P(|S| > t) dt $

So plugging it into our case:

$E[|X-Y|] = \int_0^\infty P(|X-Y| > t) = 2 \int_0^\infty P(X-Y > t) = 2\int_0^\infty(1-F_{X-Y}(t))dt$

$F_{X-Y}(t) = F_{X+Z}(t) = (F *\mu_{_Z})(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(t-s)d\mu_{_Z}(s) $

So we get

$E[|X-Y|] = 2 \int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1-F(t-s))d\mu_{_Z}(s)dt $

I have no idea whether it's a good approach or not and how to proceed.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\begin{align}
\int F(t)(1-F(t))dt &= \int P(X\leq t) P(Y>t) dt\\
&= \int 1_{x\leq t}1_{y> t}dP_X(x)dP_Y(y) dt \tag{1}\\
&= \int 1_{x\leq t}1_{y> t}dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y) dt \tag{2}\\
&= \int 1_{x\leq t}1_{y> t} dt\; dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\\
&= \int 1_{t\in[x,y)} dt \;1_{x<y}\;dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\\
&= \int (y-x)1_{y-x>0}\;dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y) \\
&=E((Y-X)1_{Y-X>0})\tag{3}\\
&=E((Y-X)^+)
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(1)}$: Law of the unconscious statistician and Fubini's theorem
$\text{(2)}$: Independence of $X$ and $Y$
$\text{(3)}$: Law of the unconscious statistician

By symmetry, $2\int F(t)(1-F(t))dt  = E((Y-X)^+) + E((X-Y)^+) = E(|X-Y|)$.

Comment: Thank you very much