# Let ${\xi}$ and ${\eta}$ have equal distribution on the interval [0;1].

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Show that despite the distribution of vector (${\xi}$, ${\eta}$), $E|{\xi}-{\eta|}\le{\frac{1}{2}}$. I was thinking about the fact that the mathematical expectation of absolute value of a random variable is an integral from 0 to + infinity of 1 minus the distribution function of the foretold random variable. But that’s all I can say right now. All suggestions are welcome

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: They are not necessarily independent, sorry:)

Answer (score 0):

The inequality does not hold when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. Consider indeed $X$ such that $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=\frac 12$ and let $Y=1-X$, so that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Then $E(|X-Y|) = E(|2X-1|)$ and $|2X-1|=1$ a.s, hence  $E(|X-Y|)=1>\frac 12$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285825/66096) $E(|X-Y|)=2\int_0^1 F(t)(1-F(t)) dt$ and the bound $x(1-x)\leq \frac 14$ for $x\in [0,1]$ yield $E(|X-Y|)\leq \frac 12$.

Comment: That may be, but I need the proof for the equally distributed random variable, whereas you disproved it for discontinuous random variable

Comment: @владимирсошников No, I disproved it for equally distributed random variables. "Having the same distribution" has nothing to do with "being continuous or discrete". And even in the continuous case you should be able to find a counterexample. Just force $X$ to be symmetric around $\frac 12$.

Comment: I think the OP means "equidistributed" (a.k.a. uniformly distributed) random variables.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from a coupling argument: by Kantorovich's duality, 
$$\sup_{\xi,\eta\sim\text{Unif}([0,1])}\mathsf E|\xi-\eta|=\inf_{\phi\in L^1([0,1])}\left(\int_0^1\sup_{x\in[0,1]}(\phi(x)+|y-x|)dy-\int_0^1\phi(x)dx\right).$$

Set $\phi(x)=\frac12-\left|x-\frac12\right|$, it is straightforward to check that
$$\int\sup_{y\in[0,1]}(\phi(y)+|x-y|)dx-\int\phi(x)dx=\frac34-\frac14=\frac12,$$
as desired.

---

**Addendum.** We do not need the full strength of Kantorovich's duality here, what is actually needed is only
$$\mathsf E|\xi-\eta|\le\int_0^1\sup_{x\in[0,1]}(\phi(x)+|y-x|)dy-\int_0^1\phi(x)dx$$
for any $\phi\in L^1([0,1])$. In this case the above inequality can be easily obtained by
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\sup_{x\in[0,1]}(\phi(x)+|y-x|)dy-\int_0^1\phi(x)dx\\
=&\mathsf E\sup_{x\in[0,1]}(\phi(x)+|\eta-x|)-\mathsf E\phi(\xi)\\
\ge&\mathsf E(\phi(\xi)+|\eta-\xi|)-\mathsf E\phi(\xi)\\
=&\mathsf E|\eta-\xi|.
\end{align}

Comment: Excuse me, what does ${\phi}$(x) mean here?

Comment: $\phi$ is any integrable function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @владимирсошников It that clear now? Please tell me if there is any confusion.

Comment: The usual duality (say for Wasserstein-1) has an infimum over the couplings (instead of a supremum like you have). Can you provide a reference ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Well, the usual duality (Kantorovich, but not Kantorovich-Rubinstein) holds for an _arbitrary_ (lower-semicontinuous) cost function $c(x,y)$, and in this case we simply replace $c(x,y)$ by $-c(x,y)$.